# Retina graphics

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using an image that fills the screen (like a background) to my app. The image is already in retina dimensions, but I scaled it to fit the simulator screen. Because it's already in retina dimensions, do I still need to add a copy of it with the @2x extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the naming notation is required for compiler to detect your retina images.if you write image.png the compiler looks for image@2x.png and then image.png and if it can not find it(for retina displays).

So name all your images xxx@2x.png and provide also xxx.png for non retina devices.

On the other hand i would use exact image sizes for non-strechable images in you app.Resizing means extra time and naturally extra computation.On the other hand fractional image resolutions ends up with blurry images.

For iphone 5 images you should for instance include Iphone5BackgorundIamge@2x.png but call Iphone5BackgorundIamge.png in your code.

Comment: That makes sense. I've added copies of all my images with the @2x addition, but when I run the retina simulator, it uses the small non-retina versions. Is this normal for just the simulator?

Comment: you imageViews have same bounds as you iamges and you have right image sizes for both versions of images?

Comment: Actually the problem seems to be that it's not adjusting the image correctly when I set the background. It cuts off much of the image and then tiles in the extra space.

Comment: Nevermind, it's my laptop's small screen size not fitting the retina simulator in. Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you enable ratina display in your application??

Comment: do not bother with the screen the new simulator does not fit to my wide screen either i have to rotate it left to see the whole app screen at once = )

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use separate images, normal & normal@2x. if you only use single image, small images will be distorted while bigger image will look squeezed.

Answer (score 2):

don't forget the iphone 5 for background images for example.
3 images are required : `Background-568h.png` `Background.png` `Background@2x.png`

```
   if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height > 480.0f) {
    // for the iPhone 5
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-568h.png"]];
} else {
    // for iphone 3.5 inch retina /non retina.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iphone dont have to do with image dimension but it uses image name for  checking whether it is to be used as ratina or normal image.You have to keep a normal size image with it's name like "image1.png" for normal display and ratina size image as "image1@2x.png" for ratina display.If your used image is already of ratina display then keep it with @2x format and put one half size image with normal name.